# Android 2.3 emulator crashed after a requestLocationUpdates call

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, android-sdk-2.3

On older versions (<2.3) there was no problem with this app. When I start the application on an Android 2.3 emulator it starts with a 'home screen' then I send the GPS coordinates. After sending the coordinates the emulator stops all his processes and tries to do a restart, but then it hangs.

If I comment the requestLocationUpdates call the emulator does not crash…

See the logcat output under this message.

```
12-30 10:31:28.174: INFO/DEBUG(31):
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 12-30 10:31:28.185: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3/GRH55/79397:eng/test-keys' 12-30 10:31:28.194: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 89, tid: 229  >>> system_server <<< 12-30 10:31:28.194: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000 12-30 10:31:28.205: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r0 00000000  r1 405155a0  r2 4128fcbc  r3 46282c74 12-30 10:31:28.205: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r4 0000012d  r5 00000000  r6 405155a0  r7 4128fcbc 12-30 10:31:28.205: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r8 84301321  r9 84302240  10 00100000  fp 00000001 12-30 10:31:28.215: INFO/DEBUG(31):  ip 82f0e7d4  sp 46282c60  lr 82f0ab37  pc 82f07d0e  cpsr 00000030 12-30 10:31:28.845: INFO/DEBUG(31):         
#00  pc 00007d0e  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so 12-30 10:31:28.845: INFO/DEBUG(31):   
#01  pc 0000ab32  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so 12-30 10:31:28.845: INFO/DEBUG(31):   
#02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so 12-30 10:31:28.855: INFO/DEBUG(31):         
#03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so 12-30 10:31:28.855: INFO/DEBUG(31):         
#04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so 12-30 10:31:28.865: INFO/DEBUG(31):   
#05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so 12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around pc: 12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07cec ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0  12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07cfc bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082  12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d0c 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002  12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d1c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082  12-30 10:31:28.885: INFO/DEBUG(31): 82f07d2c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002
```

etc.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the same problem as: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015.

Hopefully Android will fix this problem soon.